Ubuntu Budgie besides Windows 11 Secure Boot problem after installed
I just install Ubuntu Budgie besides Windows 11 with Secure Boot enabled in the bios.
All the installation was fine, i dont encounter any error.
Then when Ubuntu ask for reboot, i rebooted and the pc goes directly into Windows 11 without asking or showing any other operative system to boot.

When Ubuntu ask where to install i select the partition that says EFI.
What i can do?
If it is necessary more info i can use the live Ubuntu and put some commands from there.

I suspect that this issue is not a secure boot issue, but an issue with boot order priority and selection. If you have access to the bios boot settings, please examine the list of boot options, and you'll see an additional boot option for booting Linux in the list.
You just need to move it up in priority to the topmost, so that it gets selected before the widows option, and you should be able to boot to Linux, instead of windows first.
An additional but optional step would be to add an option to the Linux boot loader(I'm assuming grub) to chain boot to the windows boot loader, so that you don't need to change the boot priority back, when you need to boot to windows instead of Linux. For how to do this, the boot-loader documentation should have examples you can adapt to your needs.
